# Math.E equals 0.99.... ^ max int

Tags: javascript, floating-point

A friend showed me that (at least, in the google chrome console) the following statement prints true:

```
1/Math.pow(0.9999999999999999, Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) === Math.E
```

And indeed, `1/Math.pow(0.9999999999999999, Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)` is `2.718281828459045`.

This can't be a coincidence?!

Could someone explain what is going on behind the scenes to make this work?

According to [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0.9999999999999999%5E9007199254740991), the correct value should be approximately `1/0.40628` which is approximately `2.4613566998129373` -- very far off from `Math.E`. (I am assuming that wolframalpha is more precise in its calculations than javascript, but I may be wrong).

Any explanation would be appreciated.

Bonus: What is the true approximate mathematical value of that expression, I wonder?
I found this:

```
n = 0.0000000000000001
(1 - n)^MAX_INT =  1 + (MAX_INT choose 2) * n + (MAX_INT choose 3) * n^2 + ... + n^MAX_INT
```

but I have no idea how to approximate that.

I tested the above expression in [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F%281-0.0000000000000001%29%5E9007199254740991) and got `2.46` as well.

Comment: According to [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F%280.9999999999999999^9007199254740991%29+%3D%3D+E) it is the same.

Comment: @Rogier21 What do you mean it's the same? http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F%280.9999999999999999%5E9007199254740991%29

Comment: euler's number is in WA 2.718 but of you check the link above it will give the same answer as Javascript. e == 0.99^maxint = true, while the decimal values are no equal. So both JS and WA do give the same answers.

Comment: @Rogier21 I don't think that's valid since even http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F%280.9999999999999999%5E9007199254740991%29+%3D%3D+E%2B1 that link returns true. Wolfram alpha has gone crazy! (`e == e + 1`?)

Comment: Confirmed Node.js gets the same if you define Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER.  Numbers above 0.9999... are rounded to 1, so that's basically (1 - epsilon) where epsilon is the smallest unit the number can represent at that scale.  This probably has something to do with how the power converges to e, but not sure how.

Comment: And in `C#` trying `Math.Pow(0.9999999999999999, 9007199254740991)` gives `2.7182818284590451`

Comment: Does not work in Safari Console. Just checked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This arises from [the original characterisation of e as](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_%28mathematical_constant%29):

[image: e equation]

Then using the property that:

- `MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` = 2<sup>53</sup>-1, and
- `0.9999999999999999` rounds to 1 - 2<sup>-53</sup>

then

1/(1-2<sup>-53</sup>) = 1 + 2<sup>-53</sup>/(1-2<sup>-53</sup>) = 1 + 1/(2<sup>53</sup>-1)

Therefore,

1/(1-2<sup>-53</sup>)<sup>2<sup>53</sup>-1</sup> = [1 + 1/(2<sup>53</sup>-1)]<sup>2<sup>53</sup>-1</sup>

which is very close to e.

Comment: Actually, 0.999.. = 1 - 10^16. So it should be that `(1 - 10^-16)^(10^16) = very close to e`. But `2^53` is (probably) very far away from `10^16`. So this must be due to floating-point inaccuracies, not actual math (according to actual math, as wolfram alpha shows, it should be around `2.4`). I think the better answer is the one that explains that `Math.pow` uses `Math.log` and `Math.exp` internally.

Comment: Actually, `0.9999999999999999` will be rounded to the nearest Double, which is `0.99999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875`, or *exactly* 1-2^-53

Comment: This mathematical identity is a much more direct explanation of what's going on here than my answer.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because, after the comment about how `0.9999999999999999` is `0.99999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875`, I think this answer makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 7):

`pow(x, y)` is typically computed as `exp(log(x) * y)`, so let's start there.

We have:

- `x = 0.9999999999999999`, which rounds to `x = 1 - eps` (where `eps == 2^-53`).
- `y = 2^53 - 1` i.e. `y = 1 / eps` (approximately).

So we're actually calculating `exp(log(1 - eps) * 1/eps)`.

The [Taylor series expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Examples) of `log(1 - k)` is `-k - k^2/2 - ...`, but in our case all the higher-order terms will be truncated.

So we have `exp(-eps / eps)`, or `exp(-1)`, which is `1 / e`.

---

<sub>Demonstration:</sub>

```
1 - 0.9999999999999999                  //  1.1102230246251565e-16
Math.log(1 - 1.1102230246251565e-16)    // -1.1102230246251565e-16
1 / Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER             //  1.1102230246251568e-16
```

Comment: Yep. Just confirmed that `Math.log(0.9999999999999999) * Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` is really close to `-1`.